# Batch - extract specific word from a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to extract a specific word from a paragraph using DOS commands/script. I am setting the text to a variable.

```
set "Status=matched: 15:19:39 03/15/2016    from=10.18.20.116   oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2 trap= n/a   specific= n/a   traptime=2822 hours 58 minutes 52 seconds   community=NOM   agent=10.18.20.116  version=v2c var1=1016273298 var2=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2    var3=vmsitescope01  var4=1470979 Active Job Completed with Exit Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March 15, 2016 3:19 PM Job: 2726538 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-DD-Linux-ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES Exit Status: 58 (can't connect to client) Client: ipreavpada01nb New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion Status OpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment:     var6=Client Job Completion Status   var7=   var8=   var9=FMSOPSCENTER01"
```

i am  trying to extract var9 value which is FMSOPSCENTER01.

I am trying to use '=' as a delimiter in a for statement and extracting second value for testing.

```
for /F "delims==" %G in ('%status%') DO (set "State=%H")
```

But its throwing a "Client: was unexpected at this time."

Some help would be appreciated.

-Abhi

Comment: Single quotes `'` tells `for /f` that it's a command. Use double quotes `"` to tell it, it's a string. And you should use `tokens=...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Status=matched: 15:19:39 03/15/2016    from=10.18.20.116   oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2 trap= n/a   specific= n/a   traptime=2822 hours 58 minutes 52 seconds   community=NOM   agent=10.18.20.116  version=v2c var1=1016273298 var2=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2    var3=vmsitescope01  var4=1470979 Active Job Completed with Exit Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March 15, 2016 3:19 PM Job: 2726538 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-DD-Linux-ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES Exit Status: 58 (can't connect to client) Client: ipreavpada01nb New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion Status OpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment:     var6=Client Job Completion Status   var7=   var8=   var9=FMSOPSCENTER01"

for %%a in (!Status!) do (
   if "!var!" equ "var9" (
      set "var9=%%a"
      goto break
   ) else (
      set "var=%%a"
   )
)
:break
echo var9 = %var9%
```

In this method a plain `for` command is used to separate all tokens in Status variable by space or equal-sign (or comma or semicolon, the default delimiters in the set of values of FOR command); then, just take the token after the "var9" one.

**EDIT 2018/04/27**: *New method added*

The new method below allows to get the value of all `var#` variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Status=matched: 15:19:39 03/15/2016    from=10.18.20.116   oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2 trap= n/a   specific= n/a   traptime=2822 hours 58 minutes 52 seconds   community=NOM   agent=10.18.20.116  version=v2c var1=1016273298 var2=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2    var3=vmsitescope01  var4=1470979 Active Job Completed with Exit Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March 15, 2016 3:19 PM Job: 2726538 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-DD-Linux-ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES Exit Status: 58 (can't connect to client) Client: ipreavpada01nb New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion Status OpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment:     var6=Client Job Completion Status   var7=   var8=   var9=FMSOPSCENTER01"

set "Status=%Status: var=" & set "var%"

echo var5="%var5%"
echo var9="%var9%"
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini for providing the entire code. That worked like magic. Thanks all for your replies.

Comment: Actually i need both values from var5 and var9 in 2 different variables. I am referencing the above code and trying it out myself. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Extracting var5 is a tricky one.. it contains too many words. 

var5=Alert Raised on: March 15, 2016 3:19 PM Job: 2726538 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-DD-Linux-ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES Exit Status: 58 (can't connect to client) Client: ipreavpada01nb New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion Status OpsCenter Server: 

FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment:

If i change parts of code provided by Aacini, i just get the first word of var5 which is "Alert".

-Abhi

Comment: To do this we need a precise delimiter between variable values. I think at first that three spaces may work, but there are variables separated by more spaces _and_ there are values that contain three spaces! This is an interesting problem. I suggest you to post a new question and be _very precise_ in these details...

Comment: @Aacini, couldn't string replacement be used to turn the string into multiple lines and have a `FOR /F` read it.  Essentially replace the string `  var` with a line feed and the word var.  I thought I have seen someone on Dostips do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another method:

```
set "Status=matched:  15:19:39 03/15/2016   from=10.18.20.116   oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2 trap= n/a   specific= n/a   traptime=2822 hours 58 minutes 52 seconds   community=NOM   agent=10.18.20.116  version=v2c var1=1016273298 var2=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2    var3=vmsitescope01  var4=1470979 Active Job Completed with Exit Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March 15, 2016 3:19 PM Job: 2726538 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-DD-Linux-ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES Exit Status: 58 (can't connect to client) Client: ipreavpada01nb New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion Status OpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment:     var6=Client Job Completion Status   var7=   var8=   var9=FMSOPSCENTER01"
REM remove from beginning to (including) "Server: ":
set "status=%status:*Server: =%"
REM get the first token from the remaining string:
for /f %%a in ("%status%") do set "status=%%a
echo %status%
```

Comment: This solution assume that the value after "Server" is the same than the value of var9, but the question have not any reference on this point... Of course, you may use _the same method_ to get the value after "var9".

Comment: ah - there it is. I looked for the desired string and found it after "Server: ". But you are right, with this solution you can search for any token you wish (as long as the value is a single word). @Abhinandan Aithal : you may want to replace `*Server: ` with `*var9=`

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "Status=matched: 15:19:39 03/15/2016    from=10.18.20.116   oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2 trap= n/a   specific= n/a   traptime=2822 hours 58 minutes 52 seconds   community=NOM   agent=10.18.20.116  version=v2c var1=1016273298 var2=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2    var3=vmsitescope01  var4=1470979 Active Job Completed with Exit Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March 15, 2016 3:19 PM Job: 2726538 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-DD-Linux-ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES Exit Status: 58 (can't connect to client) Client: ipreavpada01nb New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion Status OpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment:     var6=Client Job Completion Status   var7=   var8=   var9=FMSOPSCENTER01"

set "var9=%status:"=%"
set "var9=%status:&=%"
set "var9=%var9:* var9=%"
set "var9=%var9:~1%"
IF "%var9: =%" neq "%var9%" (
 REM need to remove space and eveything after
 FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,25) DO IF "!var9:~%%a,1!"==" " SET "var9=!var9:~0,%%a!"&GOTO done
)
:done
ECHO "%var9%"

set "var9=%status:"=%"
SET "var9="%var9: =" "%""
FOR %%a IN (%var9%) DO (
 SET "varx=%%~a"
 IF "!varx:~0,5!"=="var9=" SET "var9=!varx:~5!"&GOTO done2
)
:done2
ECHO "%var9%"
```

The first `set` removes quotes from `status` and assigns the result to `var9`.

Then remove `&` from `var9`.

The next `set` changes "*anycharacters*<kbd>Space</kbd>var9" to *nothing*

The next `set` removes the `=` (assuming the first "<kbd>Space</kbd>var9" is the critical string)

Next we test whether there is anything following the "var9=xxx". If so, then look for the space, grab the substring and forcefully terminate the loop. I've assumed that the string-to-be-retrived is <25 characters long.

Then there is a second routine that may suffice.

The first `set` removes quotes from `status` and assigns the result to `var9`.

The next `set` changes '<kbd>Space</kbd>' to '"<kbd>Space</kbd>"' and puts quotes each end of the result. The consequence is that the string becomes a series of quoted-strings.

Next, process each of the quoted strings in turn. If the first 5 characters are 'var9=' then remove those first 5 and terminate the loop.

Note that this solution requires `delayedexpansion` and may exhibit sensitivity to some symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this question is both old and already answered. Here is another way to do it. The apostrophe in the string had to be escaped with another apostrophe. This should not be a problem with data from a file or other stream.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "Status=matched: 15:19:39 03/15/2016    from=10.18.20.116   oid=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2 trap= n/a   specific= n/a   traptime=2822 hours 58 minutes 52 seconds   community=NOM   agent=10.18.20.116  version=v2c var1=1016273298 var2=.1.3.6.1.4.1.1302.3.12.10.2.0.2    var3=vmsitescope01  var4=1470979 Active Job Completed with Exit Status 58   var5=Alert Raised on: March 15, 2016 3:19 PM Job: 2726538 Tree Type : Server  Tree Name : ALL MASTER SERVERS Nodes : fmsnbu700 Job Policy: FMS7-DD-Linux-ALL_LOCAL_DRIVES Exit Status: 58 (can''t connect to client) Client: ipreavpada01nb New State: Done Alert Policy: Client Job Completion Status OpsCenter Server: FMSOPSCENTER01 Comment:     var6=Client Job Completion Status   var7=   var8=   var9=FMSOPSCENTER01"

SET "var9="
SET "var5="
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    " '%S%' | Where-Object { $_ -match 'var5=(.*) \w\w:' } | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] } "') DO (SET "var5=%%a")
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    " '%S%' | Where-Object { $_ -match '.*var9=(.*)\s*' } | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] } "') DO (SET "var9=%%a")
ECHO var5 is %var5%
ECHO var9 is %var9%
```

Comment: Dumb question: why you changed the names of variables (`Status` to `S`, and `var9` to `R`)? The real question: how to extract "both values from var5 and var9 in 2 different variables" as the OP requested?

Comment: I feel confident that the OP is smart enough to connect S with Status. I see nothing about capturing var5 in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042294/batch-extract-specific-word-from-a-variable/50059301?noredirect=1#comment59801260_36048400) (written more than 2 years ago!) and the next comment below that one...

Comment: @Aacini - Ok, please see the edited answer for capturing `var5` not mentioned in the question. I do not like the regex there, but no time to improve it. This is not a very "regular" string. How did you get a link to a comment?