# Extraction of string from a line using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delimiter

I have data in the below manner:

```
adb.hghgjjk.hkdhdl.Connhhhjj=hjkld\:hjkld\:thin\:hjdkdl\:3000\:abcdefg
```

I want to extract "`abcdefg`" from the above line using batch.

Above data can be changing so we need to read from the end of the line to backside and stop near `:` (colon) delimiter and extract it.

Any sugeestions?

Comment: I have found a similar question, in case it helps you. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042294/batch-extract-specific-word-from-a-variable)

Comment: i think that does not work for me because they have hardcoded the values. for me the "abcdefg" can be of any length. so i need to go from the back and stop near  : (colon) and extract it.

Comment: Is the data being retrieved from a file or is it a variable? If it is being retrieved from a file is it the only line in the file?, the first line of the file? the last line of the file? and/or what method are you using to parse the file in order to isolate that particular piece of data?

Comment: @Compo, data is present in the variable

Comment: How did you get the data into the variable in the first place. I ask because that method may be improved to get just the information you need instead of having to do it later. Can you perhaps provide the appropriate portion of your script which outputs that data to the variable, _so that any answers can be better integrated into your it_.

Answer (score 2):

Normally we do not give out code without the user at least making an attempt at trying to write some code and put some effort into researching the problem.  Simple philosophy behind that is teaching a man to fish versus giving them the fish.

Give this a try.

```
@echo off
set "string=adb.hghgjjk.hkdhdl.Connhhhjj=hjkld:hjkld:thin:hjdkdl:3000:abcdefg"
set "first=%string::=" & set "last=%"
echo %last%
pause
```

If your data will never have a semicolon that you need to keep you could do this as well.

```
@echo off
set "string=adb.hghgjjk.hkdhdl.Connhhhjj=hjkld:hjkld:thin:hjdkdl:3000:abcdefg"
set "string=%string::=;%"
FOR %%G IN (%string%) do set "last=%%G"
echo %last%
pause
```

And one more example for good measure.  The nice thing about batch files is alot of times there is more than one way to skin a cat.

```
@echo off
set "string=adb.hghgjjk.hkdhdl.Connhhhjj=hjkld:hjkld:thin:hjdkdl:3000:abcdefg"
:loop
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G IN ("%string%") do (
    set "last=%%G"
    IF NOT "%%~H"=="" (
        SET "string=%%~H"
        GOTO loop
    )
)
echo %last%
pause
```

Comment: i have tried this @squashman . below is the code             `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  FOR /f "tokens=6 delims=:" %%z IN 
 ("adb.hghgjjk.hkdhdl.Connhhhjj=hjkld\:hjkld\:thin\:hjdkdl\:3000\:abcdefg") do (
   SET extractedsid=%%z
   ECHO !extractedsid!
     ) `

Comment: can you please explain or provide info on each code which you have shown above. @Squashman

Comment: Nice collection +1. @prudhvikrishna in the first code example the variable first get's assigned variable string contents after every `:` is replaced with `" & set "last=` this is a sort of self modifying code.

Comment: The line `set "first=%string::=" & set "last=%"` is a real kick. Can you say more about that or point to some place to read about it?

Comment: @lit, this technique was discovered on [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429). You can even build pseudo arrays with this technique.

Comment: @Squashman,@lit.@LotPings, still did not understand. can any one tell me how this working ?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell can use regex expressions. The result is put into the `R` variable. If there is no match, `R` will be nothing.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "S=adb.hghgjjk.hkdhdl.Connhhhjj=hjkld\:hjkld\:thin\:hjdkdl\:3000\:abcdefg"
SET "R="
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    " '%S%' | Where-Object { $_ -match '.*:(.*$)' } | ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] } "') DO (SET "R=%%a")
ECHO R is %R%
```